# Mysql retriving the nth record

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table named EMPLOYEE containing the following attributes

```
(EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, JOB_ID, MANAGER_ID, Salary)
```

Can I
Display the Nth highest salary drawing employee details
Please help

Comment: Is this about `first record with 'N-th' salary`, or `all records with N-th salary`?

Comment: Suppose the salary column contains value (6700,6400,6000,5400,3200,1200) in descending order .I would like the details containing salary 6000 ie the 3rd highest salary .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Salary INT)

INSERT INTO Test
VALUES (100), (200), (300), (400), (500)

SELECT * FROM Test
```

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 3 Salary FROM Test ORDER BY Salary DESC)q
ORDER BY Salary ASC
```

In your Sub-query SELECT TOP Nth the rest remains the same and it will get you the desired results

Comment: your question has sql tag in it and this code works like a charm in sql-server not to sure about the mysql stuff.

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` where `10` is `n + 1`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY
    Salary DESC
LIMIT
    10, 1
```

(If you want the first record, use `LIMIT 0, 1`. For the tenth, use `LIMIT 9, 1` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`try this`

`put n > 1 to get corresponding results`

n=3 must give you second `highest salary`

```
 SELECT *   --This is the outer query part 
    FROM Employee Emp1
    WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
    FROM Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```